Why is this construction of the differential coordinate-invariant?
In Lee's Smooth Manifolds the differential of a function $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ is defined as covector field $$df:v\mapsto vf$$ where $v$ is some element of the Tangent space at a point on $M$. After this definition, Lee writes the following:

Here, $\lambda^i$ is just $dx^i$. My question is why this construction is coordinate invariant, as Lee claims in the final line.

This comment comes dangerously close to answering your question, but: I don't see any coordinates in the definition you quote. So I don't see where your question is coming from.

Given any $v\in T_pM$, there exists a curve $c: I \rightarrow M$ such that $c(0)=p$ and $c’(0)=v$. The differential of $f$ is defined to be $$df_p(v) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t).$$

@Deane: that's not the definition the OP is using. They quote the definition $df(v)=vf,$ which involves no coordinates. Incidentally, the definition you bring up is not really coordinate-free: you've introduced a coordinate $t$ on the interval $I$ (admittedly, it doesn't involve any coordinates on $M,$ which I guess is what you're going for).

@WillR, thanks. What I should have written is $$ vf(x) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t)). $$ And, yes, the entire point of this is to show that the definition of $df$ does not depend on coordinates on $M$. An input parameter such as $t$ is required. You can't define a derivative without an input parameter and an output parameter.

@Deane: we're veering onto a tangent here but I have to object to your last sentence. Assuming that by "parameter" you mean a coordinate like $t,$ what you write flies in the face of the definition the OP quoted. $df(v)=vf$ is clearly a definition which has no dependence on any parametrisation - unless by "parameter" you just mean "(function) argument".

Yes, an "input parameter" is the argument to a function. There is a lot hidden under the surface of the notation $vf$. it's impossible to define $vf$ rigorously from scratch without using coordinates. At some point you have to write something in coordinates and prove it is independent of the coordinates used. This usually occurs in the definition of a tangent vector $v$ is. After that, you can do almost everything tangent vectors using only the fact that any tangent vector is the velocity vector of a parameterized curve. "Parameterized curve" means there is an input parameter, often named $t$.
